# Best practices while update/insert to a database

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I'm using the following class to handle the database transactions, but the problem is that when my client come up with a faulty database update i cannot roll back the DB into the old state where everything was fine. So is there any best practice to achieve this.

```
public class DBConnection
    {
        static SqlConnection connection;

        public void getConnection() {

            try {
                connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=PC-DILUKSHAN\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=EMS;User ID=user;Password=1234");
                connection.Open();

            }catch(Exception e){

                throw e;
            }

        }
        public DataTable executeSelectQuery(String sql) {

            try
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                // Create a DataAdapter to run the command and fill the DataTable
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
                da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);

                return dt;

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                throw e;
            }
            finally {

              connection.Close();
            }

        }

        public void executeUpdateQuery(String sql) {

            try {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }catch(Exception e){

                throw e;
            }
            finally
            {
                connection.Close();

            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: Why you can't roll back? Any explanation for that!

Comment: i haven't done any rollbacks so far, is there a feature to do that?

Comment: There ***is*** a feature for that.  Look up "Transactions" in the SQL Server documentation.  It's best to check the docs than have us give you te short version.  Plenty to understand, you know...  Actually, so save time, here's the link to the correct documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174377.aspx

Comment: Yes, first of all I don't see you are using transaction at all in your code. Use transaction, then if anything goes wrong you can always rollback and go to pristine state.

Comment: as others are saying, your key search word is Transaction

Answer (score 1):

Use the SqlTransaction object. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zayx5s0h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is an example on how to rollback a transaction:

```
private static void ExecuteSqlTransaction(string connectionString)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();

        SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
        SqlTransaction transaction;

        // Start a local transaction.
        transaction = connection.BeginTransaction("SampleTransaction");

        // Must assign both transaction object and connection 
        // to Command object for a pending local transaction
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.Transaction = transaction;

        try
        {
            command.CommandText =
                "Insert into Region (RegionID, RegionDescription) VALUES (100, 'Description')";
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            command.CommandText =
                "Insert into Region (RegionID, RegionDescription) VALUES (101, 'Description')";
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            // Attempt to commit the transaction.
            transaction.Commit();
            Console.WriteLine("Both records are written to database.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Commit Exception Type: {0}", ex.GetType());
            Console.WriteLine("  Message: {0}", ex.Message);

            // Attempt to roll back the transaction. 
            try
            {
                transaction.Rollback();
            }
            catch (Exception ex2)
            {
                // This catch block will handle any errors that may have occurred 
                // on the server that would cause the rollback to fail, such as 
                // a closed connection.
                Console.WriteLine("Rollback Exception Type: {0}", ex2.GetType());
                Console.WriteLine("  Message: {0}", ex2.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i have to add 2 things to your code. First use `using` for the `Transaction`. Scond catch one the `Exception` you are able to handle